# How to add custom visualisations to apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to add a custom visualisation to apache superset, but sadly most of the examples are outdated. i.e the files that I am meant to make changes are either non-existent or the code structure has changed significantly.

Can anyone help me with steps to follow in order to add a custom visualization